# Seeking Scott's original LCF paper

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, type-theory, domain-theory

Is the following manuscript publically available?

> Dana Scott, 1969, *A theory of computable functions of higher type*. Unpublished seminar notes, 7 pages, University of Oxford.

There is a discussion of this paper in section 8.1.2, *Types as sets*, in Cardone & Hindley, 2006 [History of Lambda-calculus and Combinatory Logic](http://www-maths.swan.ac.uk/staff/jrh/papers/jrhhislamweb.pdf); additionally section 10.1, *Domain theory*, traces back to this manuscript some crucial order-theoretic insights.

Comment: Did you try emailing him? dana.scott@cs.cmu.edu

Comment: Dana is reading this...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Published as:

Scott, D. A Type-Theoretical Alternative to ISWIM, CUCH, OWHY.
   Theoretical Computer Science, vol. 121 (1993), pp. 411 - 440.

See also:

Scott, D. Some Reflections on Strachey and his Work. in: A Special Issue
   Dedicated to Christopher Strachey, edited by O. Danvy and
   C. Talcott.  Higer-Order and Symbolic Computation, vol. 13 (2000),
   pp. 103-114.

and:

Gordon D. Plotkin, Set-theoretical and other elementary models of the λ-calculus,
   Theoretical Computer Science, vol. 121 (1993), pp. 351-409.

Comment: It's a special kind of awesome when the author themself shows up to answer a question !

Comment: Especially when the author is Dana Scott. :)

Comment: first Turing award winner on cstheory, or am i missing someone?

Comment: And I saw Gordon Plotkin walking past the restaurant window in Iceland yesterday....

Comment: I think I need to lie down ...

Comment: Well, this is wonderful and thank you - I assume I should thank Andrej as well for receiving this answer.  A further question: are the two 1969 titles really used to denote one unchanging manuscript? John Longley, 2010, [Notions of computability at higher types I](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/jrl/Research/notions1.pdf), describes the paper as 7 pages long, while the 1969 parts of the 1993 paper weigh in at just under 26 pages.